# Control name found at Design time but does not exist at Build time

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

So i have this XAML in a Window and have named the control `MyBrowser`:

```
<Grid>
    <WindowsFormsHost>            
        <forms:WebBrowser Name="MyBrowser"  ScriptErrorsSuppressed="True"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind im passing the Uri to be displayed.

```
public partial class AuthWindow2 : Window
{
    public AuthWindow2(Uri uri)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MyBrowser.Url = uri;            
   }
}
```

> While typing this intellisense finds the controlled named MyBrowser
>   without any issues but at Build time it says:
>
> 'AuthWindow2' does not contain a definition for 'MyBrowser' and no
>   extension method 'MyBrowser' accepting a first argument of type
>   'AuthWindow2' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

It seems really basic, but i cant figure out why such a simple thing isnt working.

If i name the Grid or the WindowsFormsHost controls i can access these and build without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Name` to `x:Name` of the WebBrowser

```
<forms:WebBrowser x:Name="MyBrowser" ScriptErrorsSuppressed="True" />
```

Answer (score 2):

WebBrowser is not a FrameworkElement, hence setting its `Name` property does not generate a field in your MainWindow class.

You must use `x:Name` instead of `Name` to get a generated field:

```
<forms:WebBrowser x:Name="MyBrowser" .../>
```